# Error to Insert data into a AWS S3 database table using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jython

I am trying to insert data into a AWS S3 database table using Python. 
I am getting optional second argument must be a list or tuple in error, for some reason, 
my data isn't getting inserted into the database.
the code is below,

```
    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('testing')
    cursor = context.cursor()
    sql_data = [0,2,3,4,5,6]
    for x in sql_data:
        print(x)
        query =  "INSERT INTO items (id) VALUES (%s);"""
        cursor.execute(query, sql_data)
        #or
        #cursor.execute(query, x)
```

when i write / REPLACE ABOVE QUERY WITH below query it works but i want insert data from array.

```
"""insert into items (id) values (1)"""
"""insert into items (id) values (2)"""
"""insert into items (id) values (3)"""
```

I am getting **optional second argument must be a list or tuple** ERROR

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS S3 database table"? You do not seem to be using S3 in your code aside from retrieving a bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Replace `%s` with `?`

Comment: replaced,but data not inserted .Is there any errors in query?

Comment: Your question was about the error, so here is the answer. Now, in order to proceed with why there are no records, you will have to explain first the question John asked. Please update your question with an answer.